# ng-if inside a form tag?

Tags: angularjs

**Logic:**

```
if(condition)
    Use first `<form ng-submit="action1">`
else
    Use second `<form ng-submit="action2">`
```

**Logic in PHP approach:**

```
<?php

if(condition){
    echo "<form action='action1.php' >";
}
else{
    echo "<form action='action2.php' >";
}
echo "....many many many inputs here...";
echo "</form>";

?>
```

What I'm trying to write is something like this: (I'm using AngularJs)

```
<form ng-submit="action1" ng-if="condition1"> ---> First condition
<form ng-submit="action2" ng-if="condition2"> ---> Second condition if first condition fails
....Many many many inputs
</form>
```

But of course I can simply write something like this: (would be a pain in the ass)

```
<div ng-if="condition1"> ---> First condition
    <form ng-submit="action1" >
    ....Many many many inputs
    </form>
</div>

<div ng-if="condition2"> ---> Second condition if first condition fails
    <form ng-submit="action2" >
    ....Same inputs as in the first div
    </form>
</div>
```

My question is, is it possible to use `ng-if` (I also tried `ng-disabled`) inside a `<form>` tag?

What I'm trying to avoid is to re-code all my `inputs` inside the `form` if the only change I will make is the opening `<form>` tag.

I've searched for an answer and found nothing and the only thing that's left is to confirm and ask.

Comment: You probably can do something like 
`<form ng-submit="{condition1 ? action1:action2}">`... not sure about the syntax.

Comment: You can use expression in ng-submit. Try `ng-submit="{condition1 ? action1() : condition2 ? action2() : action3()}`

Comment: second condition should simply be `!condition1`

Comment: @FuzzyTree, you're right. It's just an example. I have more than two conditions in my real code.

Comment: @zcui93, I tried the code like yours but doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Sorry, maybe try to remove the `{}`

Answer (score 1):

If the difference is only the function you want to call on submit, you can do the test in the function itself.

```
<form ng-submit="mySubmit" >
    ...Many many many inputs
</form>
```

Controller

```
$scope.mySubmit = function(){
    if($scope.condition1){
        // call the function 1
        action1();
    }else{
        // call the function 2
        action2();
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reasons, as long as it's possible, I want my `conditions` to not put inside my controller. Well thanks for the thoughts. It makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after a long try, [zcui93](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2710486/zcui93) and [abimelex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1059828/abimelex) codes seems to work **without** the `{}` (curly braces):

So the code will be:

```
ng-submit="condition1 ? action1() : condition2 ? action2() : action3()"
```

Please confirm if it also works with you. But it really works for me.